# html image tag with blur corners

Tags: html, css

I was just trying to add blur corners to an inline image tag and its not working.

I want the inline image tag styled us the `background` image tag as can see below, how would this be done?

```css
.test {
  background: url(http://via.placeholder.com/350x150) left top no-repeat;
  box-shadow: 25px 25px 50px 0 white inset, -25px -25px 50px 0 white inset;
  width: 350px;
  height: 150px;
}

img {
  box-shadow: 25px 25px 50px 0 white inset, -25px -25px 50px 0 white inset;
  width: 350px;
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">

<div class="test"></div>
```

Comment: no sure if there we can do inset shadow with img element

Comment: yea @TemaniAfif me to thats why i was asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a trick, creating  a container and putting a layer over your image that can fake the blur effect.

As per this [LINK](https://bavotasan.com/2011/adding-inset-shadow-to-image-css3/) i just used an `div` intead of an `a`.

---

Working version

```css
.test {
  background: url(http://via.placeholder.com/350x150) left top no-repeat;
  box-shadow: 25px 25px 50px 0 white inset, -25px -25px 50px 0 white inset; 
  width: 350px;
  height: 150px;
}

.image-container {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}
.image-container::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;
  box-shadow: 25px 25px 50px 0 white inset, -25px -25px 50px 0 white inset;
}
.image-container img {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-container">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">
</div>
<br style="clear:both" />
<div class="test"></div>
```